# Change the content of a line in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to get a line number containing a name from command line.
Then I want to change that name with a new name.
Then print the new line.
I'm here:

```
echo -n "enter name"
read name
grep -n "$name" file
```

It will return for example 3 entries

```
1)Sofia : 432-4567
2)
3)
echo "Which line will be changed?"
read number
```

Now I want to change Sofia with Lorie in line 1,
and print:

```
The new entry is Lorie : 432-4567
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which uses `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Enter name: " name

grep -n "$name" file || { echo "'$name' not found in file." >&2; exit 1; }

read -p "Which line do you want to change? " number

# Note: You should check to make sure that a valid
#       line number was entered.

# Define variables containing the name to replace and its replacement.
old=$name
new='Lorie'

# Use Sed to modify the line of interest in the input file.
# A backup of the original file is saved as file.bak.
# Note that, to avoid confusion, all literal parts of the Sed
# script are maintained as *single*-quoted strings, with values from
# shell variables *spliced in* (as variable references inside a *double*-quoted string).
sed -i.bak "$number"' { s/^'"$old"' :/'"$new"' :/; }' file

# Report the modified line.
echo "The new entry is: $(sed -n "$number"' {p;q;}' file)"
```

Note: If you do *not* want the original file to be backed up, the syntax depends on what implementation of `sed` you're using:

- GNU `sed`: `sed -i ... # simply do not append a value to -i`
- BSD `sed`, also used on OSX: `sed -i '' ...  # -i requires a separate, empty argument`
- If your `sed` doesn't support `-i` altogether, use the following idiom:

  - `sed ... file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Comment: Hi need Sofia and Lorie to be variable

Comment: I got this error Sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command

Comment: @Leili: Try again - sounds like you're using _GNU_ `sed`, which means that no space is allowed between `-i` and `.bak`.

Comment: @Leili: Did using `-i.bak` instead of `-i .bak` not fix the problem?